# GWs from Kerr BHs

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, kerr-metric

A rotating neutron star can emit GW radiation if it has some ellipticity (Maggiore Gravitational Waves Vol I for example), even if we neglect spindown. I would think that a Kerr BH is not a spherical object (there are cosines in the place where I'd read off it's "radius" in the metric for example). Why then do they not emit gravitational radiation? What if it's accreting mass and it spins up, rendering the metric effectively time-dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rotating neutron star whill only emit gravitational waves if it is not axially symmetric (around its rotation axis). An axially symmetric neutron star will not emit gravitational waves.

A Kerr black hole - although not spherically symmetric - is still perfectly axially symmetric around its rotation axis*, and does not emit gravitational waves (and is in fact stationary as pointed out in the answer by Jerry Schirmer).

*The "cosines" that you see in the metric are all cosines of $\theta$, the polar angle. Non-axisymmetric terms, would be terms depending explicitly on $\phi$.

Comment: "*An axially symmetric neutron star will not emit gravitational waves.*" - Is it not true that in addition to the axial symmetry, the star must also be axially static (or "stationary" if preferred)? For example, if a spherical planet hits a neutron star along the axis of rotation, gravitational waves would be emitted despite the axial symmetry. Would they not? Or else, the neutron star decides to eject some matter along its axis of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

The kerr spacetime has a timelike killing vector, so there can be no time-dependent radiation field, and the quadrupole term in GW radiation has explicit time derivatives in the source present.

If it accretes matter, then the infall of the matter can distort the black hole and this can produce gravitational radiation.  But that is also true of a schwarzschild black hole.

The process of a distorted black hole horizon gradually asymptoting to Kerr form and emitting gravitational waves in the process is known as [black hole ringdown](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.9.041060) and is relatively well-studied, particularly in the context of "having to understand gravitational wave signatures for LIGO/LISA".